# How to hide folder from search engines using htaccess

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to hide admin folder from search engines using htaccess? I know it can be done using robots.txt but robots.txt itself is accessible easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to password protect the entire admin folder using `.htaccess`.

Enter the following into your `.htaccess` file in the folder you would like to lock.

```
AuthUserFile /absolute_path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administration Area"
Require valid-user
```

Then use [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html) to generate a username and password, the generated file should be stored at the location specified by `/absolute_path/to/.htpasswd`

You should also be able to add an `.htaccess` file into you `admin` folder and check the user agent and block access this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Crawler
# fill up with other user agents you would like to block here
# and redirect to some other page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/404.html
```

Comment: i do my own authentication so no one can access the admin area...i just want to hide the folder from search engines...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really daunting to come up with a lis of all the the user agents and keep in mind that search agent value can be faked also.

Having said that following will work for most of the search engines:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|adsbot-google|bingbot|msnbot|psbot|gigabot|twitterbot|linkedinbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|pingdom\.com_bot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder-to-hide/ - [L,F,NC]
```